# About HAXM in Windows 10 14393 on My Surface Pro 4

Tags: android, windows-10, haxm

I install Windows 10 new version today (14393/1607) on My Surface Pro 4 . But When I install intel haxm to use x86/x64 android simulator, it can not start .

I uncheck hyper-v on the Control Panel -> Program. I restart my computer haxm start fail too. It give me this : 
  CPU acceleration status: Unable to open HAXM device: ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

I try to run this script it reruen this : (sc query intelhaxm)
  **SERVICE_NAME: intelhaxm
        TYPE               : 1  KERNEL_DRIVER
        STATE              : 1  STOPPED
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 577  (0x241)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0**

I run another script , it return this :

**[SC] StartService: OpenService FAILED 5:
  Access is denied.**

Who can help me to solve this ? Thx !
 PS : I have no any firewall in my computer . My device is Surface Pro 4

Answer (score 0):

Since I clean installed my Windows 10 1607 last night during the haxm installation a windows popup tells me that the driver signature is rejected.

I suspect Intel must first update their driver signature for haxm to work again.

further reference: [Windows Blog about driver signature changes in 1607](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windows_hardware_certification/2016/07/26/driver-signing-changes-in-windows-10-version-1607/)

Answer (score 0):

Checking the blog link you can see that disabling Secure Boot will disable this check. After I disabled Secure Boot the driver worked fine.

Comment: I would definitely advise against disabling secure boot... It is called secure boot for a reason.

Comment: I agree, but so far this is the only way I found to fix this, until intel update the drivers